# Rails: Getting tIDENTIFIER Syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting an error on the following code:

`<%= Warehouse.where(:product sale.product).pluck(:price) %>`

Actually it should print the price if Warehouse.product == sale.product. But it doesn't. I'm getting this error:

`SyntaxError in OrdersController#show`

`syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ')' ...= Warehouse.where(:product sale.product).pluck(:mrr) );@outp... ... ^`

`syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end ...uct sale.product).pluck(:mrr) );@output_buffer.safe_append='... ... ^`

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<%= Warehouse.where(:product => sale.product).pluck(:price) %>
```

Comment: This code should not be in views. Views are meant to be dumb.